# How to create below GUI with tkinter?

Tags: python, xml, tkinter

I'm newbie self-learning tkinter. I want to achieve below gui that was in my mind. Purpose of this gui is to compare the tag values of two identical structured XMLs. I should be able to open two xml's and compare both the tag values of left and right pane grid values.  always left and right xml structures will be consistent except values which could be different or missing.

Below is the code i managed to write by referring google and stackoverflow.

`broker1.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Broker>
    <object name="Books">
        <property name="name1"/>
        <property name="name2" value="value2"/>
        <property name="name3"/>
        <property name="name4"/>
        <property name="name5" value="value5"/>
    </object>
    <object name="furniture">
        <property name="furniture1"/>
        <property name="furniture2"/>
        <property name="furniture3" value="furniturevalue3"/>
    </object>
</Broker>
```

`broker2.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Broker>
    <object name="Books">
        <property name="name1"/>
        <property name="name2"/>
        <property name="name3"/>
        <property name="name4" value="value4"/>
        <property name="name5" value="value5"/>
    </object>
    <object name="furniture">
        <property name="furniture1" value1="furniturevalue7"/>
        <property name="furniture2"/>
        <property name="furniture3" value="furniturevalue3"/>
    </object>
</Broker>
```

Code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

HEIGHT = 700
WIDTH =  1024

canvas = Canvas(master,height= HEIGHT , width = WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

frame = Frame(master,bg = 'yellow')
frame.place(relwidth=1,relheight=1)

left = dict()  # dictionary to store name/value pairs of broker1.xml
right = dict() ## dictionary to store name/value pairs of broker2.xml

tree1 = ET.parse('broker1.xml')
#tree2 = ET.parse('broker2.xml') #yet to code for tree2 for comparision
broker = tree1.getroot()

for child in broker:
    if(child.tag == 'object'):
      for propertytag in child:
       print(propertytag)
       if(propertytag.tag == 'property'):
         print(propertytag.get('name'),propertytag.get('value'))
         left.update({propertytag.get('name'):propertytag.get('value')})

r=len(left)
valuesList    = list(left.values())

for key, value in left.items():
    entPropertyNameEntry = Entry(frame, readonlybackground='grey' , fg = 'black' , justify=LEFT,  width = len(max(left.keys(), key=len)),state='readonly')
    keyStringVar   = StringVar()
    keyStringVar.set(key)
    entPropertyNameEntry.config(textvariable=keyStringVar, relief=RIDGE)
    entPropertyNameEntry.grid(row=r,column=0)
    valueStringVar = StringVar()
    valueStringVar.set(value)
    entValueEntry= Entry(frame,readonlybackground='white', fg = 'black' , justify=LEFT, width = max(len(str(s)) for s in valuesList),state='readonly')
    entValueEntry.config(textvariable=valueStringVar, relief=SUNKEN)
    entValueEntry.grid(row=r,column=1)
    r = r - 1

master.mainloop()
```

I'm able to generate name/value pair in 2 columns but could not achieve scrolling that adjusts itself based on length of dictionaries.

Example of layout:

[image]

Comment: At a glance, this is quite overbroad -- questions should ideally be focused on as narrow an issue as possible, with everything else factored out.  If you're trying to build a table with columns that adjust their widths, ask **only** about that, with everything unrelated to table formatting (and not necessary for a [mcve] reproducing the table-formatting issue) removed from the question.

Comment: ...similarly, a question about an algorithm for diffing XML documents should be focused *only* on the XML-diffing algorithm, with no GUI elements or questions included. If, in the course of writing one program, you have questions about several aspects -- if the issues could be faced individually, they should be asked individually.

Comment: @martineau Hi.Thank you for help. I was trying the code and missed to revert it. Now corrected and tested it. Code working now.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Noted and i'll keep your suggestions in mind. my focus is in achieving the gui part. :-)

Comment: learner: With that fix in, I can now clearly see how little the code in your question is actually doing...and am sorry to say I think it's a little premature for you to be asking for as much help as doing what you want is going to require.

Comment: @martineau : this is my first ever python code. i finished the final one sometime back with treeview widget.my whole intention was to see how experienced python developers do the same gui. i really appreciate your intention to help. :-)

Comment: learner: A `Treeview` widget would be a good way to do this and might simplify some things you may want to do. There are several potential issues somewhat related to the GUI that msy need to dealt with. For example, what happens if one of the has properties the other one does or vice-versa. Other questions: Why are you making the keys and values `Entry` widgets—do you have plans to use them? Likewise, why are you using `StringVar`s in conjunction with them? Again I suspect there's design goals you haven't mentioned...that likely make this a lot of work to answer.

Comment: @martineau: agreed .. i should have put things precisely as CharlesDuffy  suggested to atleast narrow the issue to people willing to help with their precious time and effort !!